# Leaflet: Change style of map_2 on click of map_1

Tags: javascript, callback, leaflet, geojson

I'm new to Leaflet and I'm not very proficient in Javascript. I created two maps representing in map_1 the regions of Italy and in map_2 the provinces, based on the [Interactive Choropleth Map example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/).
In the first map_1 with the regions, I have the following GeoJson structure

```
var regionsData = {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[...]},
         "properties":{"reg_name":"XXXX"}}
```

In the secondmap_2 with the provinces, I have the following GeoJson structure

```
var provincesData= {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[...]},
         "properties":{"prov_name":"YYYYY","reg_name":"XXXX"}
```

My idea is to zoom in the map_2 to the selected region in map_1 and to color the provinces of the map_2 red, if these belong to the clicked region in map_1, otherwise to color these gray (see images below).

[Click of a region in map_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UABv9.png) [Color in map_2 the selected region in map_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIWlu.png)

I defined the following variables

```
var map_1 = L.map('map_reg').setView([42.5, 12.5],5);
var map_2 = L.map('map_prov').setView([42.5, 12.5],5);
var geojson_1;
var geojson_2;
```

and for the map_1 the following callback function on click action:

```
geojson_1 = L.geoJson(regionsData, {
                  onEachFeature: onEachFeatureClosure(map_1,map_2)}).addTo(map_1);
```

...

```
function onEachFeatureClosure(obj_map1, obj_map2) {
return function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    //click: zoomToFeature
    });
layer.on("click", function(e) {
    zoomToFeature_1(e, obj_map1, obj_map2)})
}
}
```

.....

```
function zoomToFeature_1(e, obj_map1, obj_map2) {
    map_2.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());

    L.geoJson(provincesData, {
        // onEachFeature:function(feature, layer) {
        style: function(feature) {
            if (feature.properties.reg_name!==e.target.feature.properties.reg_name) {
                return {'fillColor': 'yellow',};
            }
            else{
                return {'fillColor': 'yellow',};

                // e.target.setStyle({fillColor:getColor_prov(e.target.feature.properties.data_val.perc)})
            }
        // }
    }
}).update(map_2);
};
```

In my callback function *zoomFeature_1* I can zoom in the map_2 with *map_2.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());* without problem and I can set the style of the map_1.layer as follow

```
e.target.setStyle({fillColor:'#888'})
```

, but I can't change the style of the target in map_2, beacause the map_2.target is *'undefined'*.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a way to pass as argument the map_2 in the function 'zoomFeature1' and change the style of it?

Is there a way with Leaflet to color the province of map_2 on click of a region in map_1?

Comment: Have you tried to call `fillColor: 'yellow'` instead of `FIllColor`? You mess up the things a little bit or it looks like that. When you can call `map_2.fitBounds(e.target.getBoudns())` then `map_2` is already passed to the `zoomFeature1` function. Also you can't style a map, you can only style layers so please don't ask how to style the map. That `map_2.target` is undefined is clear because `map_2` has not the property `target` only the event `e` has the `target` = layer. Also you should change on `L.geoJson` the `update(map_2)` to `.addTo(map_2);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! You’re right:
1. I corrected the `fillColor:yellow` 
2. I can’t change the style of a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I corrected the function `zoomToFeature_1` as follow.

```
function zoomToFeature_1(e, obj_map1, obj_map2) {
    map_2.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    map_2.removeLayer(geojson_2);
    L.geoJson(provincesData, {
        style:   function(feature) {
            if (feature.properties.reg_name!==e.target.feature.properties.reg_name) {
                return {fillColor: 'gray',};
            }
            else{
                return {fillColor: 'red'};
            }
    }
}).addTo(map_2);
};
```